# session password issues on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: password, session, password-recovery

couldn't my session once it's locked. I've tried changing the language & displaying the virtual keyboard but it still does not work. Would it be possible to reset the password?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the password by opening the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and using the following command:

```
passwd
```

It'll ask for current password(if any) and then need to enter your new password twice.

**P.S.** Don't worry if you don't see any change in the window while typing your password. Its the Ubuntu style of security!